# How to calculate checksum by hand

Tags: power-electronics

I am a programmer and I need to send data to the machine, but I have to add checksum at the end of the data.  Can someone show me an example how to do it so I could then write an program to calculate the checksum for me.

The rules:
Bitwise inversion of the 1 byte sum of bytes beginning with the
most significant address byte and ending with the byte preceding
the checksum. (To perform a bitwise inversion, "exclusive OR"
the one byte sum with FF hex.)

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with the tag: power-electronics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition pretty well covers it.

> Bitwise inversion of the 1 byte sum of bytes beginning with the most significant address byte and ending with the byte preceding the checksum. (To perform a bitwise inversion, "exclusive OR" the one byte sum with FF hex.)

Example

- Message "Hello" = Hex: 48 65 6C 6C 6F.
- Adding these up using my Windows Calc.exe in Programmer mode I get &h01F4.
- Take the last byte and ignore everything else: &hF4.
- &hF4 XOR &hFF = &h0B - your checksum.

To clarify the last bit:

```
&hF4 = 1111 0100
&hFF = 1111 1111
       ---------
XOR  = 0000 1011 = &h0B
```

---

Update

> For some reason, it does not work for me. Here I have CA 00 01 70 00, I add them up to get 13B, I take the last byte which is 3B and XOR with FF, then I get c4, which is different from 8E(an example I got from the manual). Do I miss something about the rule?

A web search for the rule threw up a document from [NESLAB](http://www.nist.gov/ncnr/upload/Circulating-Bath_Thermo-Scientific_NESLAB-RTE-7.pdf). On page B-2 we read:

[image]

*Figure 1. The checksum region is the only part used in the checksum.*

This should explain your confusion. The lead character is not included in the calculation. Now if we run a check on CA 00 01 70 00 we can drop CA and are left with a few zeros, 01 and 70 which sums to &h71.

&h71 XOR &FF = &h8E. Voila!

Comment: Thank you. I was confused about  "Bitwise inversion of the 1 byte sum of bytes ". I did not know it means to take the last byte, but you cleared it out.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just curious, why XOR with h'FF?  Isn't this the same as just inverting each bit (0->1, 1->0).  Seems like both do the same thing to me.  Then you could represent it as "Bitwise inverted final byte of the sum of all bytes in a message"

Comment: Yes, you are correct but XOR only uses one instruction to flip all 8 bits. I can't think of a more efficient method. Can you?

Comment: For some reason, it does not work for me.  Here I have CA 00 01 70 00, I add them up to get 13B, I take the last byte which is 3B and XOR with FF, then I get c4, which is different from 8E(an example I got from the manual).  Do I miss something about the rule?

Comment: @transistor: Thanks for clarifying.  Well, I don't know the programming language, it just makes more sense to me like that.  I know in perl it's just ~variable.  I guess in practice it doesn't make a difference either way

Comment: @success: Can you post the example and maybe some of the context of the quote. I was slightly puzzled by "the most significant _address_ byte" so maybe this is a little different in some way.

Comment: I am looking and most references recommend the two's complement instead of bitwise inversion.  The difference is that you would add b'1 to the result of the bitwise inversion.  This brings the value in your example to C5, which agrees with the online calculators I checked.  Unsure about the 8E, but there are different types of checksums.

Comment: @success: cracked it. See the update.

Comment: @transistor Sorry for the late response.  I got it!  You are awesome

Comment: @jbord39 A bit late, but the reasoning behind `XOR 0xFF` accomplishes two things: 1) optimizes the receiving end by including the checksum byte in the computation. if `result==0`, checksum is correct. this is faster than comparing values. 2) the case where a checksum of 0 is computed for null data, which may be an undetected error, is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Your required checksum is calculated on data as so:

[image]

You do **not** include the lead character 0xCA in the checksum, only the shaded bytes.

A simple bit of C code to calculate your example:

```
int main()
   {
   int i; 
   unsigned char cs;
   unsigned char a[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x70, 0x00};
   cs=0;
   for (i=0; i< sizeof(a); i++)
      {
      cs += a[i];
      }
   cs ^=0xFF;
   printf("cs = %X \n", cs);
   return 0;
}
```

And the result is as expected:

```
sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                                                                              
cs = 8E
```

Since I declared the variable cs as an unsigned char it throws away the upper bits at every addition. Adding is just the same as other examples, you can throw away the upper bits at the end if you are doing it manually. Just be really careful in these cases exactly what *is* and what *is not* included in the checksum.