# RS-485: Error detection/correction mechanism

Tags: serial, rs485, error, error-correction

Does the RS-485 Standard include an error detection/correction scheme?

RS-232 has a parity bit for error detection, but I do not know anything related to error detection/correction in the RS-485 interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RS-485 and RS-232 a electrical-only standards.  The same data encoding scheme is usually used on both.  The difference is that RS-232 uses a single wire for the signal with levels below -5 V and above +5 V, while RS-485 uses a differential pair with 0-5 V levels.  RS-485 is also intended to be multi-drop whereas RS-232 is point to point.

You can chose to use a parity bit, or not, on either physical layer.

In practice, parity bits are not used much since they give a poor level of protection for the number of bits spent.  When reliability is important, chunks of data are usually wrapped in packets with more sophisticated checksums, then with a ACK/retry scheme at the level above the packets.

Comment: @Pipe: If I remember right, RS-232 is -5 to +5 volts minimum when sending, but a receiver must accept -3 to +3 V.

Answer (score 3):

RS-485 has several advantages over RS-232.

- Multi-drop from one master to multiple slave nodes.
- Differential signals for higher noise immunity.
- Lower voltages means that a 5 V PSU can be used.

With the multi-drop facility it is necessary for the transmitter and receivers to be a little smarter than may be required for RS-232 communications as addressing has to be handled. Once a micro is involved it is not to difficult to add checksum calculations too.

The parity bits are a very crude protection and will detect a single or odd number of bit errors in a character. An even number of bit errors will go undetected. In contrast, a one-byte checksum has 256 possible values and the likelihood of an undetected error is far less. For additional security a two-byte, 16-bit checksum can be used.

> Does the RS-485 Standard include an error detection/correction scheme?

No, that's up to the system designer.

For a recent question on the topic see [How to calculate checksum by hand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/247431/how-to-calculate-checksum-by-hand/247432#247432).

Comment: My absolute favourite here is [Fletcher-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher's_checksum). It's _trivial_ to calculate with the tiniest 8-bit micro if you have an add-with-carry (no expensive tables), while still offering close to the same protection as CRC-16. (Don't confuse this with Adler, who actually managed to mess it up)

Comment: Thanks, I've never come across Fletcher-16 before. Another one for the toolbox!

Comment: I don't like 255 as a modulus, since every third byte only contributes a one-in-85 choice, every fifth byte a one-in-51 choice, every fifteenth byte a one-in-17 choice, and every seventeenth byte a one-in-15 choice.  By contrast, in an Adler sum every byte contributes a one-in-251 choice.  An alternative approach is to keep two running checksums and multiply one of them by 3 with each byte (so the second-to-last byte has a 3x contribution, the third-to-last byte has a 9x contribution, etc.)  The pattern of contributions repeats every 64, but there are ways of dealing with that.

Comment: BTW, I think it's also important to note that--for better or for worse--Fletcher's checksum regards 00 and FF as identical.